# Give an example of a space which is locally compact at all but one point.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Give an example of a space which is locally compact at all but one point.

My professor told me that

> Wedge product of infinitely many circles

Will do the job. But I'm not getting his answer. Other examples will be appreciated too.

Comment: How about the real line plus the point at infinity with a neighborhood around infinity is a set that contains all numbers with sufficiently high magnitude? Then I don't think the point infinity has a compact neighborhood

Comment: Actually, this one came to me also. I'm not sure

Comment: @Mark : since $\Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to the open interval $(0,1)$ adding the point  $\infty$ with the right half-lines as neighborhoods of it will make the space homeomorphic to $(0,1]$ which is certainly locally compact at every point.

Comment: I was suggesting that each open set of infinity has right and left half lines. But I see that would give homeomorphism to a circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variation of the wedge space that your professor suggested: the hedgehog of infinite "spininess":

Let $X = [0,1] \times \mathbb{R}$, where we identify all points $(0,t)$ to a single point (equivalence class, really, we coudl call it plain $0$, the origin) with the metric:

$$d\left((x,t), (x',t')\right) = 
\begin{cases}
|x-x'| & \text{ if } t=t' \\
|x| + |x'| & \text{ if } t \neq t' \\
\end{cases}$$

so the space looks like $\mathbb{R}$ many copies of $[0,1]$ glued together at their $0$, metrically. If does not matter what representation $(0,t)$ we choose for $0$ in this computation (so the metric is well-defined).

At all points $(x,t)$ different from $0$ the space behave locally just like $(0,1]$ so is locally compact, but no neighbourhood of $0$ is compact: for some ball neighbourhood $B(0,r)$ for some $r>0$ pick $0 < s < r$ and note that $\{(s,t): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is an infinite closed and discrete subset of $B(0,r)$ showing its non-compactness. So I could have sufficed with index set $\mathbb{N}$ in the second coordinate for this...)

For a nice overview at an elementary level of such "hedgehog spaces", see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08656.pdf), e.g. They can be quite useful.

Answer (score 6):

HINT: In slightly more elementary terms what your professor is suggesting is the following.

Consider infinitely many (a numerable infinity will suffice) copies $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, ... of the circle $S^1$ with its natural topology and on each copy fix a point
$$
P_i\in C_i.
$$
Now consider the quotient
$$
X=\left.\bigcup_{i}C_i\right/\sim
$$
where the only non trivial equivalence is $P_1\sim P_2\sim P_3\sim\cdots$. Let $P\in X$ be the class of the points $P_i$. What is a neighborhood of $P$?

---

(Added later)

More generally you can consider a numerable family of pointed locally compact spaces $\{T_i, P_i\in T_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ and form the quotient space
$$
X=\left.\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}T_i\right/\sim
$$
where the $P_i$ are declared equivalent to each other, and $P\in X$ their common class. Then $X$ is locally compact at each of its points $Q\neq P$ but $P$ doesn't have a compact neighborhood since every open set $P\in U\subset X$ is of the form
$$
U=\left.\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}A_i\right/\sim
$$
with $A_i$ open in $T_i$ and $A_i\cap A_j=\{P\}$ for every $i\neq j$.

Comment: This not my question, but I am curious. What is neighborhood of $P$? Can you explain, I am having a hard time understanding. Thanks.

Comment: We need not take circles, just identifying the $0$'s in countably many copies of $[0,1]$ will do. This is not the same as my example in another answer, but this has a finer, non-metric topology, if we use the quotient topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, of course we not need circles. In fact we can take basically anything. I added a note to my answer.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost, I edited my answer including a general construction which should make the basic example more clear

Comment: @AndreaMori Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different example. Take the universal cover of a disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\widetilde{B(0,1)−\{0\}}$. Endow it with the Euclidean metric it inherits from the disk, and then take its completion with respect to that metric.